# Books as developer story item

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

Reading books is part of the developer career, and I believe they should have the same weight than for example completing a course. Personally, I read more books than I do courses, and I consider them the most important part of my evolution as developer. Having them at the bottom of the page, without any order, does not reflect how my interests as developer have been evolving through the years, and do not express how my interests as full-stack dev changes depending on the type of job I am doing at that moment.

Books do not give you a certification of completion neither a fancy flair to share, and what you accomplished by reading the book may be subjective, but they will complete the story line of many self-taught developers like me, in the way it actually happened. Judging what you got from reading a book is responsibility of whoever wants to hire you, as it is judging if you live up to your self description, skills and job descriptions.

Although I can use the "Other type of accomplishment" item (cool idea actually), by having books as first class citizen in the timeline, with the ability of specify tags, would open the door to other interesting features like "what the top 5% users of SO have been reading about in the last year". Because hiring devs is hard, but finding good books to read is also hard :)

Comment: Don't we already have books? I have a "Recommended reading" section in mine (but it's set to private because spammers -- I mean recruiters).

Comment: Oh yes that is the point, that I would like to be able of adding the books to the timeline, in the same way I can add a course, rather than having them in another section at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I missed that. Never mind :). Sounds like a fair thing to me, although not really verifiable, as most of the other things are on the timeline.